# How to Install Private Python Package as Part of Build

Tags: python, docker, pip, git-submodules

I have a fairly large private python package I just finished creating. I'd like to install it as part of my build process for an app in a Docker container (though this isn't so important). The package source is quite large, so ideally I'd avoid downloading/keeping the whole source.

Right now, I've been just passing around the package source along with my app, but this is unwieldy and hopefully temporary. What's a better way? git submodule/subtree? I'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 11):

If you use github with a private repo you will have to create a SSH deploy key and add the private key to your app folder for builds.

`pip install git+git://github.com/myuser/foo.git@v123`

Alternatively, you can mount a pip-cache folder from host into container and do pip install from that folder. You'd have to keep the python packages in the cache dir with your app.

`pip install --no-index --find-links=/my/pip-cache/`

you can install python packages to this pip-cache with the following command:

pre pip 9.0.1:

`pip install --download pip-cache/ package1 package2`

pip 9.0.1+ (thx for comment @James Hiew):

`pip install download pip-cache/ package1 package2`

Comment: private keys should not be kept with source, so you'd have to find a way to make the key available to the build process - I haven't done it this way.

Comment: `pip install --download` has been replaced with `pip download` in pip 9.0.1

Comment: with buildkit you can forward ssh keys - https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066

Answer (score 8):

You can set up a personal OAuth token in Github following the [instructions here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) and use command

`pip install git+https://<your_oauth_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myuser/foo.git`

More docs [here](https://help.github.com/articles/git-over-https-using-oauth-token).

Comment: This answer appears to be outdated. Can you please update?

Comment: what if the foo repo has submodules?
How do I pass a deploy token for submodules as well?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to mess with ssh keys use http and token authentication, but you don't want to expose your token in your repo I suggest to pass the token as an environment variable.

Add to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV GITOKEN "$GITOKEN"
RUN bash -c "pip install -r <(envsubst < requirements.txt)"
```

Set your requirements as this:

```
+plotly==2.7.0
+git+https://$GITOKEN@github.com/githubuser/your_package.git@master
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a `requirements.txt` file and you want to do `pip install -r requirements.txt` in your Dockerfile, what I do is:

- Create a `GITHUB_TOKEN` env var. Put it in `.env`
- Add it as an ARG in your `docker-compose.yml` file
- Before installing your pip packages:

```
RUN git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

That allows to patch all URLs coming from `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I'd put it in a separate private repo, then install it as a requirement using pip:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/myuser/foo.git@v123
```